# Rails order by association field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following models

```
class User
  attr_accesible :first_name, :phone_number
  has_one :user_extension
end

class UserExtension
  attr_accessible :company, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have table which contains all users. And I need to sort this table by first_name, phone_number, company.
With first_name, phone_number I don't have any problems, order works fine, in example

```
@users = User.order("first_name desc")
```

, but I also need sort by company and don't know how to do it.

And I can get company name by this way

```
@user.user_extension.company
```

So i have troubles with sql, which will gave me all users ordered by company.
DB: PostgreSQL.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

I should provide more information about this models.

```
create_table "user_extensions", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "company"
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "phone_number" 
end
```

Also, I tried use join

```
User.joins(:user_extension).order("user_extension.company desc")
```

and what i get

```
 User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_extensions" ON "user_extensions"."user_id" = "users"."id" ORDER BY user_extension.company desc
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "user_extensions" does not exist
```

on

```
User.includes(:user_extension).order("user_extension.company desc")
```

i also get

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "user_extensions" does not exist
```

**Resolved**
Have problems with my bd, all joins works fine.

Comment: how can i make it work here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451274/how-to-add-sorted-elements-in-the-filter-dropdown-in-activeadmin-rails

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try this:

```
@users = User.includes(:user_extension).order("user_extensions.company desc")
```

I think you need at `order`: `user_extensions`, not `user_extension`

Comment: Indeed. :user_extension is the association, "user_extensions" is the table name and you need to reference the table name in order clauses.

Comment: Nice! I had this exact problem!

Comment: This even works with external tables. I'm pulling data from an external SQL source and this worked!! Thanks

Comment: Why does it need to be `includes`

Comment: Great! Now where on earth is this documented in the official docs?

Comment: Note: while this works with Postgres, it does not work with Sqlite.

Comment: @Jwan622 the `includes` here will eliminate the N+1 query.  Each iteration through the loop will call `user.user_extensions`, and without `includes`, each of these calls will make an additional trip to the database. Including `includes` here will kind of preload the associations, eliminating the need for all the extra database calls.

Answer (score 24):

Merge can make the query smaller/saner-looking, and it benchmarked faster for me in Rails 4.x:

```
@users = User.joins(:user_extension).merge(UserExtension.order(company: :desc))
```

Comment: Great answer, and uses symbols.  Thank you very much.

Comment: This is the only solution I could get working for Rails 5.1  Thanks, Gary.

Comment: FYI: We aware that as Rails 5.1.1 this returns duplicated users as is common with joins. However, applying `.distinct` at the end throws an error like the following: `ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`.

Answer (score 12):

`@users = User.order("user_extension.company desc")` should work fine.

Comment: I tried your code, but unsuccessful      <br/>                                                          User.order("user_extension.company desc")
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY user_extension.company desc
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_extension"

Comment: How about `User.includes(:user_extension).order("user_extension.company desc")`?

Comment: That sounds like the table does not exist. Are you sure the migration has been run? Have you tried resetting and remigrating the DB?

Comment: @Roganartu, just curious: is there an equivalent hash syntax for associations (i.e., an equivalent to `order(company: :desc)`?

Answer (score 10):

Old topic, and perhaps off topic, but I needed this. FWIW:

### Order by association field

```
User.includes(:user_extension).order('user_extensions.company ASC')
```

Lets make it more interesting, create more associations.

### Order by the associations two levels deep.

```
User.includes(user_extension: :company).order('companies.name ASC')
```

### Order by the associations three levels deep.

```
User.includes(user_extension: { company: :guilds }).order('guilds.secret_knock ASC')
```

Comment: What if you have multiple companies associated for the same user extension and you want to sort according to the last/first company associated?

Comment: Post separate Q on SO. Specify the problem clearly, with code example and desired outcome. Feel free to link to the Q in your next comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This three level  associations helped me from a blocker

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late but I ran into a similar issue and this is how I implement it:

```rb
scope :sort_by_company, ->{
    joins(:user_extension).order(UserExtension.arel_table[:company].lower.desc)
  }
```

The code above should be placed within the `user model`.

Hope it can help!