# how to add sorted elements in the filter dropdown in activeadmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Post model, PostSource model. A PostSource has many posts, a post belong to one PostSource.

Using ActiveAdmin, in the Index action of the Post, I am displaying a filter of PostSource this way:

```
filter :post_source, label: 'Source'
filter :category, as: :select, collection: Category.order(:name).collect { |cat| [cat.name, cat.id] }
```

with the controller as:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    end_of_association_chain.includes(:post_source)
  end
end
```

It displays the source, but does not display in a sorted order. How to sort the filter in this case?

I tried adding sortable, order on filter but it does not seem to work

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Are you trying to sort the first filter or the second?

Comment: I want to sort all the sources, while they are displayed.

Comment: Your question, is answer to my question :) thanks

Comment: @Aleks: Happens with me as well many-a-times. SO it is, no thanks is solicited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to sort the first filter ('post_source'), you could just add a collection as you have in your second line, and sort within a block.

```
filter :post_source, label: 'Source', collection: proc { PostSource.order(:name) }
```

This syntax might be used as an alternative in the second example as well.

Comment: Yup, this helps. This is quite an old requirement, but as far as I remember I had tried calling the method order in PostSource, but it didn't work out. I tried this code, and it works like a charm. Anyways thanks.. :)