# Constructing an ActiveRecord with Nested Joins - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to do something similar to this: [Rails order by association field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19616611/3284936), only with an associated table. I have three models:

```
class Policy
  has_many :clients
end

class Client
  belongs_to :policy
  belongs_to :address
end

class Address
end
```

and want to create a report collection, which will contain Policies with associated clients and their addresses. Something similar to this:

```
@report = Policy.where(...)
@report.includes(:clients, :addresses).order('clients.address.state desc')
```

but, of course, there is no direct association between `Policy` and `Model` and I get `missing FROM-clause entry for table "address"`. I really don't want to add `Policy > Address` association as there are other models that have addresses and belong to policies.

Comment: You want `@report.includes(clients: [:addresses])` since addresses is an association of clients, not of Policy. That'll solve N+1 issues. If you want sorting, then you'll want to be doing joins.

Comment: ** `clients: [:address]` (singular) as Clients belong to Addresses. Still getting `missing FROM-clause entry for table "address"` for something like `Policy.where(id: (1..3)).includes(clients: [:address]).order('clients.address.address desc').ids`

Comment: Try: `@report.joins(clients: [:address])` I recommend doing this in a rails console or tailing the development.log file so you can see the SQL being generated.

Comment: @mroach same issue, unfortunately. Here is the query: `SELECT "policies"."id" FROM "policies" INNER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."policy_id" = "policies"."id" INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."id" = "clients"."address_id" WHERE ("policies"."id" BETWEEN 1 AND 3)  ORDER BY clients.address.state desc
`

Comment: You need only order by `addresses.state`. In SQL when a table is not aliased, it's referenced by its name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to do is a SQL `JOIN` to the table and then order by that table's name and the field in `table.field` notation.

```
@reports.joins(clients: [:address]).order('addresses.state')
```

Here's what's going on:

In the `joins` method we're saying we want the `clients` relation **and** its `address` relation to be included in a single query.

Next, with `order` we use `addresses` since that's the name of the underlying table. If you're ever not sure, tail you log file (e.g. `log/development.log`) or use the Rails console to see the generated SQL.

This approach has the benefit of reducing N+1 queries as well since you're gulping all your data in one query.

Comment: absolutely! I was also calling `clients.addresses` in `.order`.