# How to sort by "date associated"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A `User` has many `Airports` though `Preferences`.

I want to display the airports, sorted by "first added" to their preferences. How do I do this? Since the airports are a "static" database, their `created_date` is irrelevant. We're looking more for something like `associated_date`.

I suppose what I need to do is find the association in the join table and get *its* `created_date`.

I'm sure I can figure it out. But, does anyone have the solution close at hand?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "I want to display the airports", you mean the `airports` that are associated with the `user` through the user's `preferences`, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Preference.where.not(airport_id: nil).order(created_at: :asc)
```

This would give you back all instances of `Preference` with an airport_id in ascending order.

Additionally, this may help you out too:

[Rails order by association field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616611/rails-order-by-association-field)

An approach based on this link would be this:

```
Airport.joins(:preferences).merge(Preference.order(created_at: :asc))
```

This is assuming you have a traditional has many through association set up between `User`, `Airport`, and `Preference`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the `airports` for the `@current_user` sorted by the `created_at` date of the `preferences` that join the `airports` to the `@current_user` (whew!)...

And assuming that:

```
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :preferences
end
```

I believe you want something like:

```
@current_user.aiports.joins(:preferences).order(preferences: {created_at: :asc})
```

or `:desc`, depending on your needs.

That's not tested, so you may need to fiddle with it a bit.